# Prisma: difficulty connecting an explicit many to many relationship

Tags: node.js, postgresql, apollo-server, prisma

I'm finding it difficult to connect an explicit many to many relationship with prisma. I have also tried to do the exact same thing with an implicit relationship and get the same result.

Stack: nodejs, prisma and apollo server

Schema:

```
model User {
  id        Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  ...
  ...
  investments UsersInvestments[]
}

model UsersInvestments {
  user         User       @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId       Int
  investment   Investment @relation(fields: [investmentId], references: [id])
  investmentId Int

  @@id([userId, investmentId])
}

model Investment {
  id   Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  ...
  ...
  users UsersInvestments[]
}
```

Resolver:

```js
createInvestment: async (_, { input }, { db, user }) => {
  const investment = await db.investment.create({
    data: {
      ...input
      users: {
        connect: { userId: user.id }
      }
    }
  });
      
  return investment
},
```

Error:

```
PrismaClientValidationError: 
Invalid `prisma.investment.create()` invocation:

{
  data: {
    ...
    ...
    users: {
      connect: {
        userId: 1
        ~~~~~~
      }
    },
+   userId: Int,
  }
}

Unknown arg `userid` in data.users.connect.userid for type UsersInvestmentsWhereUniqueInput. Did you mean `select`?
Argument userId for data.userId is missing.
```

There is no information about connecting many to many relationships on the prisma docs. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a new relationship you need to create new record in `UsersInvestments` relation table. So you cannot connect to existing row, but you need to create new one. And `data.users` represent exactly this table, so you need to do following:

```
prisma.investment.create({
  data: {
    users: {
      // this creates new row in `UsersInvestments`
      create: [{
        // Here we say that this new row user will be one of existing users
        user: {
          connect: {
            id: 1
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```